# Overriding web.xml context params

Tags: java, maven, jetty, gradle

I have a maven project that I am migrating to gradle.  In the maven project I use the jetty plugin and provide an `overrideDescriptor` like this:

```
  <webAppConfig>
      <overrideDescriptor>override.xml</overrideDescriptor>
  </webAppConfig>
```

Using this, I can override some context parameters from my `web.xml` with parameters from the `override.xml`, but any parameters not in the `override.xml` will revert to the value in the `web.xml`.  This all works as expected.

Now that I am moving to gradle, I am trying to replicate this using the gradle jetty plugin.  I tried providing a `webXml` value, but it replaces the entire web.xml file:

```
jettyRun {
    webXml file('override.xml')
}
```

Is there any way I can provide the same override functionality via gradle, or am I stuck reworking my override file to be a complete replacement for my default web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try `overrideWebXml`, e.g.:

```
jettyRun {
  overrideWebXml file('override.xml')
}
```

This is a property on [AbstractJettyRunTask](http://svn.codehaus.org/gradle/gradle-core/tags/REL-0.7/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/jetty/AbstractJettyRunTask.java), and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This would be entirely within the gradle plugin so best to check the documentation for the plugin to see if there is an override option.  If not it ought to be relatively easy to add it and contribute back to that project.